# What type should I declare for my data (using TypeScript)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typeerror

This is part of my TypeScript code.

```
enum FirstEnum {
    firstEnumKey1 = 'firstEnumKey1',
    firstEnumKey2 = 'firstEnumKey2',
    firstEnumKey3 = 'firstEnumKey3',
    firstEnumKey4 = 'firstEnumKey4',
}

enum SecondEnum {
    secondEnumKey1 = 'secondEnumKey1',
    secondEnumKey2 = 'secondEnumKey2',
    secondEnumKey3 = 'secondEnumKey3',
}

// map first enum to second enum
const map: {[i in FirstEnum]: SecondEnum[] } = {
    'firstEnumKey1': [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey1],
    'firstEnumKey2': [],
    'firstEnumKey3': [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey2, SecondEnum.secondEnumKey3],
    'firstEnumKey4': [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey2, SecondEnum.secondEnumKey3],
};
```

I have two enums and a const which map them. I'm using the map to define some data that for each SecondEnum has an object. The object keys should be map keys which had that specific SecondEnum value in their array.
So now my result should be like this.

```
const getSecondEnumValuesBasedOnMap = {
    [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey1]: {
        [FirstEnum.firstEnumKey1]: 'some value',
    },
    [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey2]: {
        [FirstEnum.firstEnumKey3]: 'some value',
        [FirstEnum.firstEnumKey4]: 'some value',
    },
    [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey3]: {
        [FirstEnum.firstEnumKey3]: 'some value',
        [FirstEnum.firstEnumKey4]: 'some value',
    },
}
```

If I change my map my data should change based on it. for example if I add `SecondEnum.secondEnumKey2` to `FirstEnum.firstEnumKey2` my data should change like this:

```
// map first enum to second enum
const map: {[i in FirstEnum]: SecondEnum[] } = {
    'firstEnumKey1': [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey1],
    'firstEnumKey2': [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey2],
    'firstEnumKey3': [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey2, SecondEnum.secondEnumKey3],
    'firstEnumKey4': [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey2, SecondEnum.secondEnumKey3],
};

const getSecondEnumValuesBasedOnMap = {
    [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey1]: {
        [FirstEnum.firstEnumKey1]: 'some value',
    },
    [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey2]: {
        [FirstEnum.firstEnumKey2]: 'some value',
        [FirstEnum.firstEnumKey3]: 'some value',
        [FirstEnum.firstEnumKey4]: 'some value',
    },
    [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey3]: {
        [FirstEnum.firstEnumKey3]: 'some value',
        [FirstEnum.firstEnumKey4]: 'some value',
    },
}
```

I want to declare a type for my result so when I changed my map I get errors to update my result but I'm kind of new to typescript and I don't know how.

Comment: When you say `result` are you referring to `getSecondEnumValuesBasedOnMap`?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wQJ5GN) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes it's referring to `getSecondEnumValuesBasedOnMap` @nickzoum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, we need to change the type of the `map`, since it is currently not having literal values for the `SecondEnum` and we won't be able to determine which exact values are used.

To prevent the compiler from widening the types we will use [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) and to maintain type safety we will use [satisfies](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html) operator:

```
const map = {
  firstEnumKey1: [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey1],
  firstEnumKey2: [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey2],
  firstEnumKey3: [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey2, SecondEnum.secondEnumKey3],
  firstEnumKey4: [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey2, SecondEnum.secondEnumKey3],
} as const satisfies {[K in FirstEnum]: readonly SecondEnum[]};

// type EnumMap = {
//   readonly firstEnumKey1: readonly [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey1];
//   readonly firstEnumKey2: readonly [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey2];
//   readonly firstEnumKey3: readonly [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey2, SecondEnum.secondEnumKey3];
//   readonly firstEnumKey4: readonly [...];
// }
type EnumMap = typeof map;
```

Next, let's define a type that accepts a generic parameter constrained by `SecondEnum` and find the members of `FirstEnum` that have this specific item in the `map`. We are going to use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to map through the `map` and [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to exclude those that are not suitable, and at the end return the keys of the `map` that have this second enum in them:

```
type FindValue<T extends SecondEnum> = keyof  {
  [K in keyof EnumMap as T extends  EnumMap[K][number] ? K : never]:EnumMap[K]
}
```

Let's define a type for the `getSecondEnumValuesBasedOnMap`. We will need to use `mapped types` and `key remapping` again to exclude those second enum members that are not used at all:

```
{
  [K in SecondEnum as [FindValue<K>] extends [never] ? never : K]: {
    [P in FindValue<K>]: string
  }
}
```

Note that `[]` are really important in the `[FindValue<K>] extends [never]`, since `never` is an empty set and is a supertype for every union and to make sure that this check works as expected we prevent the compiler from distributing the types using the `[]`.
And in the values, we are mapping through the result of `FindValue<K>` which returns as the keys where the second enum is used and assigns a value of type `string`:

```
const getSecondEnumValuesBasedOnMap:{
  [K in SecondEnum as [FindValue<K>] extends [never] ? never : K]: {
    [P in FindValue<K>]: string
  }
} = {
  [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey1]: {
    [FirstEnum.firstEnumKey1]: 'some value',
  },
  [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey2]: {
    [FirstEnum.firstEnumKey2]: 'some value',
    [FirstEnum.firstEnumKey3]: 'some value',
    [FirstEnum.firstEnumKey4]: 'some value',
  },
  [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey3]: {
    [FirstEnum.firstEnumKey3]: 'some value',
    [FirstEnum.firstEnumKey4]: 'some value',
  },
};
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQJ5GN)

Comment: Thank you for your great solution and useful references. @wonderflame

Answer (score 0):

declare type like this:

```
type GetSecondEnumValuesBasedOnMap = {
[K in SecondEnum]: Partial<{ [L in FirstEnum]: string }>
```

}

then use like this:

`const getSecondEnumValuesBasedOnMap: GetSecondEnumValuesBasedOnMap = { [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey1]: { [FirstEnum.firstEnumKey1]: 'some value', }`

Comment: it shouldn't be partial. it should take the value from the `map`

Comment: sorry I understood now, can you please provide the solution?

Comment: if you are asking me then I already did put my approach in the comments under the post

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to declare the map as a type rather than a constant (assuming you do not also need to use it in your calculations).
 If you do that and also invert the keys and values to make the mapping easier, you can declare all the types like this:

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYOwrgtgBAYglgJwM4BcCi5oG8BQUoBmiqGkA0sAJ4CMUAvFAORHLqYU2MA0ehxb5KgCZ6TFiXbDuvcQIgcAzKOb9S8qgun5ZajgBZlOyZT3SAvjhyhIUAMrAAxgHsQAEzVRc+JI5fvjtAyMPs5uulTUWlAhfuGUIkExYcZCUUn+gpRKib7JmZo8FiiUAA7AUGoAKqXAALIAhiWiXlAA2vahGRAAdOlx1AC6AFywqpjdRpnUANy87bldvQtxQsOjrGoTY-lQAD7rEpBbG8Z6s-jznZt9xgpr8CdHk+pZewdyx4cvZzhmszjFMpQABq9QANmBgFUag0mgwWq0ANZUKBwEBQZGUJwECqYaplWFrFr4AD0JKgAFUQAQnAgUGAQPUUMAwZQoABJKAAd3qSBAjBQ0TACHKAAsnFyoCyfFAUE5osBBShReVAeVsbKVai3MAAB5QXlQAAG0IJjSRVAGRt4pPJAAowU4nCUkJqEE4wABzUUG6Joz1g8qYg1uTWgKAOUX1ECe4Cu5Wqmqy+UJ7nRwVc8ogYDAVwAShtbTR2YQHG1GKoGqwFcoI2DZgNrtNdXNmIGa1QCH95ygf1+-1CqCgsZQHVimFBELjACFebmAPIgWEjSeQ5uw5pzMd5Ho3KZEwutB5fT5yDiDEYAIiQTgg5QAbuDIZeePgzK+2tvFnuXqsRsS2mPD5ng4P8oGvW8HyfYAXygMkKgQd0EEPIDNhAjQ1ggu8oEfKcXxQ7YenQkxMJvbDcOfD93y3ZZxh-RQD3wC5UPGYi7ivMioLwj9mMI084j0UjIJw6D8LfQppiAA)

```
type EnumTypeMap = {
  [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey1]: FirstEnum.firstEnumKey1;
  [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey2]: FirstEnum.firstEnumKey3 | FirstEnum.firstEnumKey4;
  [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey3]: FirstEnum.firstEnumKey3 | FirstEnum.firstEnumKey4;
};

type ValueEnumTypeMap = {
  [key in keyof EnumTypeMap]: {
    // Unfortunately I wasn't sure how else to set the type of the index as `EnumTypeMap[key]`
    // (loops through a single key and then changes the type to the type we need)
    [innerKey in keyof { key: key } as EnumTypeMap[key]]: string;
  };
};

const getSecondEnumValuesBasedOnMap: ValueEnumTypeMap = {
  [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey1]: {
    [FirstEnum.firstEnumKey1]: "some value",
  },
  [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey2]: {
    [FirstEnum.firstEnumKey2]: "some value", // Error
    [FirstEnum.firstEnumKey3]: "some value",
    [FirstEnum.firstEnumKey4]: "some value",
  },
  [SecondEnum.secondEnumKey3]: {
    [FirstEnum.firstEnumKey3]: "some value",
    [FirstEnum.firstEnumKey4]: "some value",
  },
};
```